# Get data from script code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get data from a website, can I get url data from  code?

Example code:

```
<script type="application/json" id="store">
{
    "url":{"host":"localhost"},

    "resources":
    {
        "xxfff":
        {
            "stream":
            {
                "streamId":"","duration":212714,"videos":
                [
                    {
                        "url":"www.test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "url":"www.site.net"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I just want to get "www.site.net" from script code, is it possible?

Comment: `resources.xxfff.stream.videos[1].url`

Comment: Thank you but how can I get this data from a website?

Comment: Your question needs more context. Could you update it with what you are trying to do.

Comment: an axample this code on stackoverflow and I want to get this data resources.xxfff.stream.videos[1].url

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible. To demonstrate, I'm going to show you how you could create such an element in the first place, and then how to retrieve the data. If you are manually putting the code in the script tag, I would suggest stringifying it first.

```
let src = document.createElement('script');

src.setAttribute('id', 'store');

let json = {
    url : {
        host : "localhost"
    },
    resources : {
        xxfff : {
            stream : {
                streamId : "",
                duration : 212714,
                videos : [
                    {
                        url : "www.test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        url : "www.site.net"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};

json = JSON.stringify(json);

src.innerText = json;

const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const footer = document.getElementById('footer');

body.insertBefore(src, footer);

// Now you have created the element, 
// so you reverse the process to get your data

src = document.getElementById('store');

json = src.innerText;

json = JSON.parse(json);

let sites = json.resources.xxfff.stream.videos;

sites.map(site => console.log(site.url));
```

Comment: Hello @codeWonderland, I want to get url value from another website. an example this script code on stackoverflow and I want to get url value from stackoverflow.

Comment: yes, that would be the code at the bottom of the script after the comment, you have to scroll the script down

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have this script tag somewhere in your webpage, you can read it as any other tag, using `innerHTML` (right in the first line of this snippet):

```js
var json=document.getElementById("store").innerHTML;
var data=JSON.parse(json);
var videos=data.resources.xxfff.stream.videos;
var table=document.getElementById("tbl");
videos.forEach(function(urlObj){
  var td=document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML=urlObj.url;
  var tr=document.createElement("tr");
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```html
<script type="application/json" id="store">
{
    "url":{"host":"localhost"},

    "resources":
    {
        "xxfff":
        {
            "stream":
            {
                "streamId":"","duration":212714,"videos":
                [
                    {
                        "url":"www.test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "url":"www.site.net"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<table border="1" id="tbl"></table>
```

On a side note, there was a surplus comma in your original post (right before the last closing curly brace) which made the entire thing invalid. I removed it in the hopes of it was just some copy-paste issue, perhaps you had more fields just wanted to cut the post shorter.

Also, if you generate this data immediately into the page, you could just let it be "normal" script, and surround it with a simple `var data=` and `;` pair. Then it would be a variable already, without the need for parsing.